# Adobe media server / FMS : how to enter the admin panel?

Tags: adobe, flash-media-server, fms3

AFter I successfully installed FMS 5.0 on DEBIAN,  when I enter my console panel, I got:

http://myIpServer.com:1111/

```
<result>
<script id="tinyhippos-injected"/>
<level>error</level>
<code>NetConnection.Connect.Rejected</code>
<description>Admin user requires valid username and password.</description>
<timestamp>Thu 11 Dec 2014 05:28:10 AM EST</timestamp>
</result>
```

I tried both installation with apache and without apache: what am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Open the admin console by either going to `[your-ams-server].com/ams_adminConsole.htm`

or open up `ams_adminConsole.htm` locally, if you have an local installation of ams. It should be in `[ams install]/webroot`

From there you can enter in the address, username and password, and have access to the admin console.

You're just not supposed to access the admin console by going directly to port 1111